# How to make an element live() by an element's event that doesn't yet exist in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
// for example
$('#text').die('focusout');

//then I try to make it live() with a button that just exist
$('#button').live('click', function(){
    $('#text').live('focusout');
});
```

When I click on the #button, firebug tells me that something's worng in the jQuery.js. How to accomplish something like that?

Comment: You can call `$('#text').live('focusout', function(){ /.. /});` anytime you want, presuming jQuery is loaded. Having it called on a button click is not making sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) takes a second parameter of a function that you are missing

```
function liveConvert( type, selector ) {
    return (type && type !== "*" ? type + "." : "") + selector.replace(rperiod, "`").replace(rspaces, "&");
}
```

right here selector is undefined and it fails.

Comment: even with the second param, it does nothing, the script's too complex.. thanks anyway.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a function as the second parameter to your $('#text').live('focusout'); Without that callback parameter that line doesn't have any functionality anyways.

Try something like :

```
$('#text').live('focusout', function(){
    //do logic here.
});
```